# Can't install Steam, connection failed error on APT and some websites

Tags: apt, dns, steam

I wanted to play dota2 on steam, then I tried to install steam like this (btw I’m new on Linux)

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get install steam
```

I couldn’t download it. Then I wanted to open store.steampowered.com to see if there's anything there that can help me to download steam but it always says connecting and it never connects.

I have the same problem opening some other websites:

[image: cant open steam like this]

This is the error I get from APT:

```
Err:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 gcc-6-base i386 6.0.1-0ubuntu1                                                                                      
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libgcc1 i386 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libxau6 i386 1:1.0.8-1
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:4 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libxdmcp6 i386 1:1.1.2-1.1
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:5 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libxcb1 i386 1.11.1-1ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:6 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libx11-6 i386 2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:7 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libxext6 i386 2:1.3.3-1
  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
```

Comment: it says  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]

Comment: Looks like a networking issue. Your machine can't conntect to IP 185.142.156.14. Maybe an issue with a proxy or maybe a firewall blocking that ip. What output do you get from the command `curl -Is http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`? Can you open `http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` in a browser from another machine in your network?

Comment: There is a problem with your network, or network configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this :

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/pool/steam/s/steam/steam-launcher_1.0.0.48_all.deb
sudo gdebi steam-launcher_1.0.0.48_all.deb
```

You can also install it manually like this :
Open this link and download latest_steam.deb:
    https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb

Then install it like this :

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i steam-lastest.deb
```

Comment: Would be nice if people comment when they downvote instead of downvote and flee...

Comment: thanks it woked but now i cant open store.steampowered.com/

Comment: @An0n In this case you're right and what's worse is that this is the accepted answer and yet it's close to being deleted. If this answer does get deleted, post a comment to me anywhere on Ask Ubuntu with a [link to the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005450/cant-install-steam-connection-failed-error-on-apt-and-some-websites) so that I can vote to undelete it. Unfortunately the question is close to being closed too.